# Error object object y salida de bucle en letras en vez de palabras con ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

Mi problema es que no se hacer una petición ajax en condiciones y por más que he visto por internet no me sale, me coge la información bien, el problema es que al recorrerla me salen letras como muestro en la siguiente captura y si pongo datatype:json me sale el error de object object, lo que quiero es enviar y recibir. Si alguien puede dar luz a esta cuestión se lo agradecería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo 1:** este archivo **JS** envía una variable bandera booleana al archivo 2 php:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Le pasamos una variable bandera de estado 
var flagAnonimo = "true";
$.ajax({
    url: './php/Funciones.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    // Le pasamos la variable bandera
    data: { flagAnonimo:flagAnonimo },
    success: function (data) {
        

        console.log(data.id);
        var array = [];
        // Parsemos los datos para que se puedan utilizar
        var datos = JSON.stringify(data);
        var  array_resultado = JSON.parse(datos);

        console.log(array_resultado);

        for (var i in array_resultado){
            console.log(array_resultado[i]);
        }
        console.log("La variable bandera ha sido enviada y la variable unica creada." 
        );
    
        }, error: function (data) {
        console.log('Se ha producido un error.' + data);
    }
});
});
```

**Archivo 2:** Este archivo recoge la variable bandera y la mete en un método para que en la clase (archivo 3 php) haga la consulta y me la devuelva:

```
require('./clases/Persona.php');

if (isset($_POST["flagAnonimo"])) {

$flag = $_POST["flagAnonimo"];

//Le pasamos la id a la clase persona y clave unica la metemos en la variable id_unica
$persona_creada_obj = new Persona($flag);

//Llamamos al método que genera una clave unica
$persona_creada_obj->generar_id_unica($flag);

//Le pasamos el array a Funciones.js
echo json_encode($persona_creada_obj);

} 

else {
    echo "esto no avanza :'(";
}
```

**Archivo 3:** esta es la clase como tal y aquí se hace la consulta y se devuelve en un array:

```
 class Persona {
    private $flag;
    private $arrayIdEstado;

    public function __construct($flag) {
        $this->flag = $flag;
    }

    public function generar_id_unica($flag){
        //Recibimos la variable bandera de Funciones.js
        if ($flag) {
            //Generamos una id unica
            $clave = uniqid();
            //Le quitamos los 4 primeros digitos porque daría un total de 13 digitos y en la base de datos tenemos 9
            //Le decimos que lo que genere va a ser la clave unica y que la retorne
            $id = substr($clave, 0, -4);

            include('Conexion.php');

            // Como al quitarle digitos a la clave única ya no es tan única consultamos a la base de datos si está
            $consulta = "SELECT id_unica_rol FROM rol WHERE id_unica_rol = '$id'";

            // Hacemos la conexión a la base de datos
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

            // Entra si la clave ya existe
            if ($resultado == $id) {
                //Generamos una nueva id unica
                $clave_unica = uniqid();
                $id_unica = substr($clave_unica,0 -4);
                // Se la mandamos a la función de la misma clase con self
                self::insertarRol($id_unica);
            } else {
                self::insertarRol($id);
            }

            //Antes de salir cambiamos el estado de la flag porque si refrescamos la página vamos a tener la misma id y dará error
            $flagFalse = false;

            $arrayIdEstado = array("id" => $id, "flag" => $flagFalse);

            print_r($arrayIdEstado);

            return $arrayIdEstado;

        } else {
            echo "La variable bandera es false";
        }

  
    }

    // Así protegemos la inserción
    public function insertarRol($id) {
        include('Conexion.php');
        // INSERTAMOS DATOS TANTO EN LA TABLA ROL COMO USUARIO
        //Insertamos los datos primero en la de rol
        $insercion1 = "INSERT INTO rol(nombre,id_unica_rol) VALUES ('anonimo','$id')";

        //La insertamos conectandonos a la base de datos
        mysqli_query($conexion,$insercion1);

        //Cerramos la conexión con MYSQL
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

En esta parte del código la función generar_id_unica devuelve un array que no recoger en ninguna variable

```
$persona_creada_obj->generar_id_unica($flag);

//Le pasamos el array a Funciones.js
echo json_encode($persona_creada_obj);
```

Deberías recoger el resultado en una auxiliar que después envías al json_encode

```
$aux=$persona_creada_obj->generar_id_unica($flag);

//Le pasamos el array a Funciones.js
echo json_encode($aux);
```

Por otra parte tienes un print_f que debes eliminar en el archivo3

```
print_r($arrayIdEstado);
```

Esto provoca que la salida salga un var_dump q malforma el json